# Использование интерфейсов при создании объектов в java

Tags: java, объекты, интерфейс

Я сталкивался с кодом, где не всегда создание объекта происходит из класса и по принципу:

```
Cat barsik = new Cat();
```

Герберт Шилдт (Наиболее полное руководство. с.231) писал по этому поводу:

```
class A {
// это вложенный интерфейс
public interface NestedlF {
    boolean isNotNegative(int x);
}
}
// Класс В реализует вложенный интерфейс,
class B implements A.NestedlF {

public boolean isNotNegative(int x) {
    return x < 0 ? false : true;
}
}
class NestedlFDemo {
public static void main(String args[]) {
// использует ссылку на вложенный интерфейс
    A.NestedlF nif = new B ();
    if(nif.isNotNegative(10))
        System.out.println("10 не является отрицательным");
    if(nif.isNotNegative(-12))
        System.out.println("это не будет отображаться");
}
}
```

И мне лично неясно, как понимать строку:

```
A.NestedlF nif = new B ();
```

Вроде как создается объект nif, который кидает ссылку на А.NestedIF, который является объектом класса B?

Кроме того, подобное создание объектов практиковал и Хорстман (Тонкости Программирования с.130). Цитирую:

```
/**
 Демонстрация действий со связанными списками
 */
public class LinkedListTest
{
public static void main(String[]  args)
{
    List a = new LinkedList() ;
    a.add("Angela") ;
    a.add("Carl") ;
    a.add("Erica") ;

    List b = new LinkedList() ;
    b.add("Bob") ;
    b.add("Doug") ;
    b.add("Frances") ;
    b.add("Gloria") ;
// Включение слов из списка Ь в список а

    ListIterator alter = a.listIterator(); //Возвращает итератор, указывающий на начало списка

    Iterator biter = b.iterator() ; //iterator Возвращает массив, содержащий все элементы в этом списке в надлежащую
         //  последовательность (от первого до последнего элемента).
    while (biter.hasNext() ) {
        if (alter.hasNext()) alter.next();
        alter.add(biter.next());
        System.out.println(a);
                          }

        System.out.println(a) ;
// Удаление каждого второго слова из списка b
        biter = b.iterator() ;
        while (biter.hasNext()) {
    // перед вызовом метода next следует вызывать метод hasNext, который                              //возвращает значение true , если конец коллекции еще    не достигнут, и объект-//итератор может перейти к следующему элементу. */
            biter.next(); // Пропуск одного элемента
            if (biter.hasNext()) {
                biter.next();  // Пропуск следующего элемента
                biter.remove();  // Удаление этого элемента
            }
        }
    System.out.println("1");
                System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println("2");
// Коллективная операция:  удаление слов,
// которые присутствуют в списке Ь,
// из списка а
                a.removeAll(b);
                System.out.println(a);
            }
        }
```

К примеру в строке кода:

```
Iterator biter = b.iterator() ;
```

iterator - это метод интерфейса List, насколько я пониманию. Iterator - это интерфейс. 
Получается, на основе интерфейсов можно создать объект? Я не поленился, ввел

```
System.out.println(biter);
```

Жаба мне вывела:

```
java.util.LinkedList$ListItr@6d6f6e28
```

Из чего я сделал вывод, что сие есть объект.

Внимание вопрос: где есть хорошая литература о создании объектов посредством интерфейсов? В частности очень интересует использование интерфейсов с оператором ***new***.

Comment: Что-то у меня ощущение, что вы дальше 300 страницы так и не добрались. В любой уважающей себя книге есть раздел, посвященный интерфейсам и тому, что значат типы переменных. Еще скажите, что вы не знаете, что в переменной родительского типа можно хранить дочерние объекты `Parent parent = new Child();` и так с ними работать. А в типе Object можно хранить все, что угодно: `Object obj = new ЛюбойКласс();`

Comment: В контексте парадигмы наследования - мне это вполне известно. Но вопрос сводится не к любому классу. Вопрос сводится к интерфейсам.

Comment: Тоже самое касается интерфейса, если класс наследует интерфейс, он реализует все его функции и его объекты могут быть потом присвоены переменной с типом интерфейса. Почти как абстрактный класс и его наследники.

Comment: Поставил +1 к вопросу, не понимаю почему такие вопросы минусуют. Человек стремиться к знаниям, отлично изложил вопрос, да и вопрос то по теме. Развивайтесь и всё у вас получится)

Comment: +Alexey Vladimirovich мне это вдвойне непонятно, ведь русскоязычной литературы по jave, мягко говоря, не достаточно. Куча вещей не в Эккеле, не в Шилдте, не в Хорстмане толком не объяснена.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я совершенно не знаю Java, но тем не менее постараюсь объяснить.:)

Интерфейс - это некий контракт, договоренность между сервером - кодом, который предоставляет интерфейс, - и клиентом - кодом, который использует интерфейс.
В этом контракте описываются те услуги, которые клиентский код может получить от серверного кода.

Например данный контракт

```
public interface NestedlF {
    boolean isNotNegative(int x);
}
```

говорит о том, что если вы имеете дело с объектом, который предоставляет данный интерфейс, то вы можете воспользоваться его услугой `isNotNegative`.

Так класс `B` в своем объявлении декларирует, что он предоставляет перечень услуг, определенных интерфейсом `A.NestedlF`

```
class B implements A.NestedlF {

public boolean isNotNegative(int x) {
    return x < 0 ? false : true;
}
```

И он конкретно определяет эти услуги. В данном случае только одну услуг isNotNegative.

Клиентам, которым нужны услуги данного интерфейса совершенно неважно, объект какого класса предоставляет данные услуги. Им важно имеется ли такой сервис у объекта или нет.

В этом объявлении

```
A.NestedlF nif = new B ();
```

создается объект класса `B` и объявляется ссылка на этот объект, как ссылка на интерфейс. То есть клиентскому коду объявляется, что имеется такой сервис, описанный в интерфейсе, предоставляемый некоторым объектом. И клиенты могут воспользоваться этим сервисом, то есть интерфейсом, который предоставляет объект класса `B`.

Имея дело с ссылкой, объявленной как `A.NestedlF nif`, клиентский код, который использует эту ссылку, ничего не знает, объект какого именно типа предоставляет этот интерфейс, но он знает, что используя эту ссылку, можно обратиться к сервису (к методу) `isNotNegative`

```
if(nif.isNotNegative(10))
    System.out.println("10 не является отрицательным");
if(nif.isNotNegative(-12))
    System.out.println("это не будет отображаться");
```

В данном конкретном случае этот сервис предоставляет объект класса `B`.

Интерфейс позволяет объединять совершенно различные классы, несвязанные между собой иерархией наследования, в одну группу, и обращаться к объектам классов, используя единый интерфейс, который в каждом классе может быть реализован по-своему.

Например, если бы у вас был еще один класс, класс `C`, который также предоставляет услуги данного интерфейса, то вы могли бы написать

```
//...
class C implements A.NestedlF {

public boolean isNotNegative(int x) {
    System.out.println( "Это шутка!" );
    return true;
}
}
//...
class NestedlFDemo {
public static void main(String args[]) {
// использует ссылку на вложенный интерфейс
    A.NestedlF nif = new B ();
    if(nif.isNotNegative(10))
        System.out.println("10 не является отрицательным");
    if(nif.isNotNegative(-12))
        System.out.println("это не будет отображаться");

    C c = new C();
    nif = c;

    if(nif.isNotNegative(10))
        System.out.println("Спасибо, я понял.");

}
}
```

Comment: Уважаемый @vlad-from-moscow спасибо за комментарий, а можете два предложения добавить, а то не очень ясно. Какие поля будут у объекта, который создан таким образом?

Comment: @Andrew Kachalin У объекта B нет заданных пользователем полей. Он реализует только интерфейс, то есть функцию член класса, которая объявлена в соответствии с определением интерфейса.

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы тут описываете в народе называется полиморфизмом. Используется сплошь и рядом. Из литературы могу посоветовать [Философия Java](http://www.ex.ua/4884921). А так можете просто больше почитать конкретно о полиморфизме.

Comment: А на какой странице Эккель что-то пишет по поводу создания объектов с помощью интерфейсов? Я специально всю субботу перечитывал его. И что-то не нашел. Может смотрел плохо?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, да, скорее всего плохо прочитали мой ответ и смотрели плохо. О полиморфизме там много чего написано.

Comment: RTFM - это не ответ. Тот же Эйкель писал по этому поводу: Глава 8
... В этой главе рассматривается полиморфизм (также называемый динамическим связыванием, или
поздним связыванием, или связыванием во время выполнения).
А динамическое связывание ≠ то, о чем я спрашивал.